# Remove Trailing Slash from WordPress URL (The site also don't have www)

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help as I am confused a lot with .htaccess

Some months back, I removed WWW from the URL of my domain name using following .htaccess lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My current .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now, I also want to remove the trailing slash from the URL, as because I am using WordPress and a page/post will open, no matter if there's a trailing slash or NOT!

I request you to please provide me the .htaccess code, so that I can REMOVE the trailing slash. Kindly remember, I don't want WWW also and I have already set .htaccess rule for the removal of WWW

Note: 3 Years back when I started the blog, I set the Permalinks Structure without trailing slash. Now, suddenly Google Webmasters Tools is showing warnings. I mean to say, both of these URLs are opening the same page/post:

```
http://example.com/about/
```

and

```
http://example.com/about
```

Also, the URL for rel="canonical" is WITHOUT trailing slash

If you require any more details, I will be happy to provide

Comment: the WWW can be easy removed by setting the blog url in the wp settings.

Comment: Hi, I have already removed WWW. I want to remove the trailing slash "/" from URLs, so that they redirects to URLs WITHOUT Trailing Slash. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with .htaccess file. Can you please tell me where to put the code? I want to REDIRECT all "URLs with Trailing Slash" in them TO "URLs without Trailing Slash". Sorry, I am a noob in .htaccess :(

Comment: Put it below the RewriteCond line.

Comment: I get this error in browser: The page isn't redirecting properly and the site don't load at all :( Is there any way, I can contact you personally with my site URL? Thanks :)

Comment: mrintech.com - Right now, If you open any post/page WITH or WITHOUT trailing slash, it will load in the browser.

Comment: Try this RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [R,L]

Comment: Error: This webpage has a redirect loop in chrome

Comment: Sir, my .htaccess file is very big because I am using W3 Total Cache Plugin. This plugin has also inserted lots of rules in .htaccess

Comment: Hello Sheikh Heera Sir, I can fully understand that you are unable to rectify my problem without actually looking into my .htaccess file and by hit & trial methods. Anyways, I will work on this myself and I would like to thank you for your precious time and support. You rock :)

Comment: Please look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess and http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/, if it hrlps.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: actually yeah the ? seems pointless in this instance as does the [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L]
seems a lot more sensible unless there's a reason for needing an actual redirect rather than a simple rewrite

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with .htaccess file. Can you please tell me where to put the code? I want to REDIRECT all "URLs with Trailing Slash" in them TO "URLs without Trailing Slash". Sorry, I am a noob in .htaccess :(

Comment: Makes 2 of us, I was only really looking at the regex bit.  Dunno, after RewriteBase looks good to me.

Comment: Take out the [L] as well so WP rules can do their thing.

Comment: error: Moved Permanently. Sir, my .htaccess file is very big because I am using W3 Total Cache Plugin. This plugin has also inserted lots of rules in .htaccess

Comment: Hello Beeblbox Sir, I can fully understand that you are unable to rectify my problem without actually looking into my .htaccess file and by hit & trial methods. Anyways, I will work on this myself and I would like to thank you for your precious time and support. You rock :)